# 2D Vectors Char to Int

Tags: c++, vector, char, int

I am trying to convert a 2D Vectors of randomly generated chars to int. For example, if the chars are 'abc' then I want my int vector to be '97,98,99' etc.

I tried looking on here and for the most part, people are asking about char to sting, string to char, etc.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<vector<char> > vec(100, vector<char>(10));
    vector<vector<int> > intVec(100, vector<int>(10));
    srand(time(NULL));
    int intAscii = 0;

    // Fill 2D vector with random chars
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
       rand_num = (rand() % 8 + 3);
       for(int j = 0; j < rand_num; j++)
       {
           //logic here... randomly gen a char and place it in the same position, but this time in the int vector as an int. 
           vec.at(i).push_back((rand() % 26 + 97));
           intAscii = int(vec.at(i).at(j));
           intVec.at(i).push_back(intAscii);        
   }


   // Print Contents & print out the int vector. 
   for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) 
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < vec.at(i).size(); j++)
       {
           cout << vec.at(i).at(j);
           cout << intVec.at(i).at(j);
       }
   }
}
```

The problem that I am running into is that when it prints out both vectors, chars is fine, for int I am getting a whole bunch of zeros. Which doesn't seem right because the `int(vec.at(i).at(j))` works i.e if char vector was `a` then the int vector would be `97` and so on.

At this point, my guess is that the syntax for the int vector might be wrong.

Comment: Why do you have 100 vectors of size 10 and still use push_back()?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're going for in your example, but it feels like you're just going about it the wrong way. Start with an empty vector and add things to it. You don't need 2 vectors, you can print characters as integers very easily. Don't use magic numbers, if you mean 'a' use that. https://ideone.com/Jg3yLQ

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry I should have been clearer. The reason why I have the char array that size is because I have to gen a 2d array of 100 words that vary from a columns size of 3 - 10.

Comment: Why not a vector of string then? That seems more appropriate to me. *shrug* https://ideone.com/k2uTpe

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
intAscii = (int)vec.at(i).at(j);
```

In addition, to access the elements it could be better to use indices instead of push_back, like:

```
intVec.at(i).at(j) = intAscii;
```

This should work because you already allocate memory for your vector at the very beginning.